# Get Sub-String from third or forth specific character to end of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a number of records in the table as shown below, where I have put the structure of the table and the records that are in conflict for you.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblHilfeStrings]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HilfeStrings] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TblHilfeStrings] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And this is my insert query:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TblHilfeStrings] ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TblHilfeStrings] ([Id], [HilfeStrings]) 
VALUES (1, N'Startzeit_ist_von_8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TblHilfeStrings] ([Id], [HilfeStrings]) 
VALUES (2, N'Verspätung_von_11_bis_12_Uhr_wegen_Ölen_der_Maschine')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TblHilfeStrings] ([Id], [HilfeStrings]) 
VALUES (3, N'Wassermotor_und_Dampfgeneratorausfall_und_dessen_Reparatur_von_8.00_bis_12.00_Uhr,_die_auf_morgen_verschoben_wurde')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TblHilfeStrings] ([Id], [HilfeStrings]) 
VALUES (4, N'Die_gesendeten_Spesen_wurden_vom_Arbeitgeber_nicht_genehmigt')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TblHilfeStrings] OFF
```

And what is the problem? Actually, I need a function with which I can enter a character and its repetition place (for example _ and 3) from the third place where the _ character is located to the end of the string and show me what There are characters from _ to the end. The structure should look something like this:

| Hauptsaite | Chaehd-String | Anzahl der Zeichen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Startzeit_ist_von_8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr | 8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr | 40 |

Meanwhile, I searched a lot on the Stack Overflow website, but I did not find anything similar to this request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SubStringByPosition (@text varchar(256), @search_exp varchar(1), @position int)
RETURNS varchar(256)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    declare @len int = 0;
    declare @i int = 0;
    declare @pos int = 0;

    set @len = len(@text);

    while(@i < @position and @pos < @len)
    begin
        set @pos = charindex(@search_exp, @text, @pos + 1)
        set @i = @i + 1
    end
    
    RETURN(substring(@text, @pos + 1, @len - @pos));
END;
```

Try to use this function in your query:

```
SELECT  [Id], [HilfeStrings], dbo.SubStringByPosition(a.HilfeStrings, '_', 3) AS SubStr
FROM [TestDb].[dbo].[TblHilfeStrings] a
```

if you need to build table as your example, use this code:

```
SELECT AA.*, LEN(AA.[Chaehd-String]) AS 'Anzahl der Zeichen' FROM (
SELECT [HilfeStrings] AS 'Hauptsaite', dbo.SubStringByPosition(a.HilfeStrings, '_', 3) AS 'Chaehd-String'
FROM [dbo].[TblHilfeStrings] a) AS AA
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. can you improve you function to give table structure function?

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by that? Can you please get to me more details about it?

Comment: No problem. another point. your function returns one character less.  for example when I ran  `select  dbo.SubStringByPosition(N'Startzeit_ist_von_8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr' , N'_', 3) as M1` it returns  `8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uh`  instead of `8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr` please check it. thanks.

Comment: and referring to my first comment if I want to get the result something like that you can see in my question I should repeat your function two times: 
`select N'Startzeit_ist_von_8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr' as Hauptsaite, dbo.SubStringByPosition(N'Startzeit_ist_von_8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr' , N'_', 3) as [Chaehd-String], LEN(dbo.SubStringByPosition(N'Startzeit_ist_von_8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr' , N'_', 3)) as [Anzahl der Zeichen]`

Comment: Thank you! 1. Please check my post, I fixed my function. 2. You don't need to call my function two times (it works), but much better use two selects.

Answer (score 1):

Try following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStringAfterSpecificCharacter]
(
    @MainString NVARCHAR(4000),
    @DelimiterCharacter NCHAR(1),
    @DelimiterPlace int
)
RETURNS Table
AS 
RETURN
(

WITH SplitedStrings(Ends,Endsp)
    AS (
        SELECT 0 AS Ends, CHARINDEX(@DelimiterCharacter,@MainString) AS Endsp
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Endsp+1, CHARINDEX(@DelimiterCharacter,@MainString,Endsp+1)
            FROM SplitedStrings
            WHERE Endsp > 0
    )
        SELECT f.Hauptsaite, f.DataStr as [Chaehd-String], LEN(f.DataStr) as [Anzahl der Zeichen]
    FROM (
        SELECT 'RowId' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'DataStr' = SUBSTRING(@MainString,Ends,LEN(@MainString)-(1 - Ends)),
        Hauptsaite = @MainString 
        FROM SplitedStrings
    ) f WHERE f.RowId = @DelimiterPlace + 1
)
```

Based on your request, you wanted a `Table-Valued` Function.
**How to use:**

```
select * from [dbo].[GetStringAfterSpecificCharacter] (N'Startzeit_ist_von_8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr', N'_', 3)
```

The result:

| Hauptsaite | Chaehd-String | Anzahl der Zeichen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Startzeit_ist_von_8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr | 8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr | 40 |

With the following method, you can have the result on the main table and run the function on the table and have the complete output for all the records of the main table:

```
declare @DelimiterCharacter NCHAR(1) = N'_',    @DelimiterPlace int = 3
declare @TempTable as table 
(
Hauptsaite varchar(4000) , 
[Chaehd-String] varchar(4000), 
[Anzahl der Zeichen] int
)

declare @TempMainTable as table 
(
[Id] [int] NULL,
[HilfeStrings] [varchar](200) NULL
)

insert into @TempMainTable 
select * from [dbo].[TblHilfeStrings]

while((select count(*) as cntRecs from @TempMainTable) > 0)
begin
insert into @TempTable (Hauptsaite , [Chaehd-String] , [Anzahl der Zeichen])
SELECT d.Hauptsaite , d.[Chaehd-String], d.[Anzahl der Zeichen] from  [dbo].[GetStringAfterSpecificCharacter]((select top(1) t1.HilfeStrings  from @TempMainTable t1 order by t1.Id) , @DelimiterCharacter , @DelimiterPlace) d
    delete from @TempMainTable where Id = (select top(1) Id  from @TempMainTable order by Id)
end
select te.Hauptsaite, te.[Chaehd-String], te.[Anzahl der Zeichen] from @TempTable te
```

The result:

| Hauptsaite | Chaehd-String | Anzahl der Zeichen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Startzeit_ist_von_8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr | 8.00_bis_20.00_Uhr,_Abfahrt_um_23.00_Uhr | 40 |
| Verspätung_von_11_bis_12_Uhr_wegen_Ölen_der_Maschine | bis_12_Uhr_wegen_Ölen_der_Maschine | 34 |
| Wassermotor_und_Dampfgeneratorausfall_und_dessen_Reparatur_von_8.00_bis_12.00_Uhr,_die_auf_morgen_verschoben_wurde | und_dessen_Reparatur_von_8.00_bis_12.00_Uhr,_die_auf_morgen_verschoben_wurde | 76 |
| Die_gesendeten_Spesen_wurden_vom_Arbeitgeber_nicht_genehmigt | wurden_vom_Arbeitgeber_nicht_genehmigt | 38 |

If you find the answer useful, please tick it as a favorite answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I checked your method. It's an interesting solution, but a little bit complicated to solve this simple task. Much better use a while loop.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @igdmitrov But I used `while((select count(*) as cntRecs from @TempMainTable) > 0)` you can find it in second part . . . Oh ok. you mean I have to use While loop in my function. ok That's great idea.

Comment: Yes, I mean my post with a function which has a little code and is readable. I added you in my network on LinkedIn.

Comment: I checked the code you sent. It ran without any problems and displayed the output I wanted. Only in terms of performance, I feel that the execution speed of this function is a bit slow @AliNajafZadeh .